# Mysql insertion failing in script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have been breaking my head against this and still I am unable to understand that why wouldn't this work

```
include ("db_conn.php");

//function for sanitizing the user input
function clean_input($data)
{
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = trim($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
//registration form data validation
if(!empty($_POST['s_register_submit']))
{
$Salutation= $F_Name= $L_Name= $email= $pass= $P_Number = "";

$Salutation= clean_input($_POST['Salutation']);
$F_Name= clean_input($_POST['F_Name']);
$L_Name= clean_input($_POST['L_Name']);
$email= clean_input($_POST['email']);
$pass= clean_input($_POST['pass']);
$P_Number= clean_input($_POST['P_Number']);
$query= "INSERT INTO STUDENT (Salutation, F_Name, L_Name, email, password, phone) 
         VALUES
         (`$Salutation`,`$F_Name`,`$L_Name`,`$email`,`$pass`,`$P_Number`)";

$query1= mysqli_query($dbhandle,$query) || die("Unable to insert"); 
echo "Saved";
```

And here are the contents for db_conn.php

```
$user="root";
$password="";
$host="localhost";
$dbname="Interns";

$dbhandle=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
if(!$dbhandle)
{
die("Unable to connect");
}
echo "Connected";
```

When running db_conn.php directly or through the script in which it is included, its echoing "Connected", still the query returns "Unable to Insert".

Comment: Try $query1= mysqli_query($dbhandle,$query) || die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));  to get the error message from mysql.

EDIT: Thank you VolkerK. Adjusted the code acordingly.

Comment: @Markus Müller: mysqli_error($dbhandle). Unlike mysql_error() with the mysqli the handle is not optional.

Comment: Appears like @JohnConde spotted the bug. I had this impression that back ticks are used to avoid ambiguity between keywords and variables.

Answer (score 3):

You wrap strings in quotes, not ticks. Ticks are reserved for identifiers.

```
$query= "INSERT INTO STUDENT (Salutation, F_Name, L_Name, email, password, phone) 
     VALUES
     (`$Salutation`,`$F_Name`,`$L_Name`,`$email`,`$pass`,`$P_Number`)";
```

should be

```
$query= "INSERT INTO STUDENT (Salutation, F_Name, L_Name, email, password, phone) 
     VALUES
     ('$Salutation','$F_Name','$L_Name','$email','$pass','$P_Number')";
```